# Ignoring exception from a finished function using PDFKit & GCF

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, pdfkit

So at the moment i;m trying to generate a PDF (using Node.js, PDFKit and GCF) from a number of data within my Firebase Database.  One of those items is an image URL but PDF kit requires this in a base64 format.  At the moment the PDF is being created but i'm getting around 6 calls of "Ignoring exception from a finished function".

I think this is to do with the base64 function but i can't seem to nail down where the issue is... the function is returning its results after the onCreate is triggered but i thought "await" is meant to stop this?  Any help / thoughts?

```
 exports.onAppComplete = functions.database.ref("users/{appId}").onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{
            var appId = context.params.appId;
            var appDb = admin.database().ref(`Applications/${appId}`);
            return Promise.all([appDb.once('value'),appId]).then(([applicationDb, appId])=>{

                var application = {
                    appId:appId,
                    dogId:applicationDb.child("dogId").val(),
                    userId: applicationDb.child("appWith").val(),

                  };


                const Logo =  admin.database().ref(`users/logouri`);
                return Promise.all([Logo.once('value')]).then(([Logo])=>{
                    const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
                    let doc = new PDFDocument({ margin: 72 });
                       doc.size = [595.28, 841.89];
                       doc
                       .image('./images/logo.png', 50, 45, { width: 100 })
                         .fillColor("#444444")
                        .moveDown(1);
                        var logoUri = Logo.val();
                        console.log("pictureURL",logoUri);
                         toBase64(logoUri,50,50,doc);


                    const myPdfFile = admin.storage().bucket().file('/test/Arbeitsvertrag.pdf');
                    const stream = doc.pipe(myPdfFile.createWriteStream());
                    doc.end();
                    return console.log('Successfully made App PDF:', "OK");

                })
                 });
                });
          function toBase64(url, x, y, pdfdoc) {
                        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)=>{
                            var https = require('https');
                            var req = await https.get(url, (res) => {
                                res.setEncoding('base64');
                                let body = "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64,";
                                console.log("BODY", body)
                                res.on('data', (d) => {
                                    body += d;
                                });
                                res.on('end', () => {
                                    console.log("END", body)
                                    pdfdoc.image(body, x, y);
                                    resolve(res);
                                });
                            });
                            req.on('error', err => {
                                console.error('error!');
                                reject(err);
                            });

                        });

                    }
```

I'm using Node.js 8 and there is a seperate logo that is loaded locally.

Comment: await doesn't simply stop your program to wait for something else.  It's more complicated than that.  It just makes asynchronous code look synchronous so that it's easier to read and write.  I suggested investing some time to learn how promises work in JavaScript in order to write effective Cloud Functions.  Without a good understanding, your functions will fail in mysterious ways.

Comment: thanks doug, so from what i can gather a Promise.All would solve the issue but how would i call a promise.all on the function Base64?

Comment: Doug, any help with this one?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some prompting by doug...here's the code that answers this, it turns out that a Promise.all is key:

```
exports.onAppComplete = functions.database.ref("users/{appId}").onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{
            var appId = context.params.appId;
            var appDb = admin.database().ref(`Applications/${appId}`);
            return Promise.all([appDb.once('value'),appId]).then(([applicationDb, appId])=>{

                var application = {
                    appId:appId,
                    dogId:applicationDb.child("dogId").val(),
                    userId: applicationDb.child("appWith").val(),

                  };


                const Logo =  admin.database().ref(`users/logouri`);
                return Promise.all([Logo.once('value')]).then(([Logo])=>{
                    const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
                    let doc = new PDFDocument({ margin: 72 });
                       doc.size = [595.28, 841.89];
                       doc
                       .image('./images/logo.png', 50, 45, { width: 100 })
                         .fillColor("#444444")
                        .moveDown(1);
                        var logoUri = Logo.val();
                        console.log("pictureURL",logoUri);
                         return Promise.all([toBase64(logoUri),doc,application]).then(([logoURIBase64, doc, application])=>{

            doc.rect(0,0,590,70,40).fillAndStroke("#339999");
            doc.image(logoURIBase64,50,50,{width:100});
        const myPdfFile = admin.storage().bucket().file('/test/Arbeitsvertrag.pdf');
        const stream = doc.pipe(myPdfFile.createWriteStream());
        doc.end();
        return console.log('Successfully made App PDF:', "OK");

            });


                    const myPdfFile = admin.storage().bucket().file('/test/Arbeitsvertrag.pdf');
                    const stream = doc.pipe(myPdfFile.createWriteStream());
                    doc.end();
                    return console.log('Successfully made App PDF:', "OK");

                })
                 });
                });
          function toBase64(url) {
                        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)=>{
                            var https = require('https');
                            var req = await https.get(url, (res) => {
                                res.setEncoding('base64');
                                let body = "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64,";
                                console.log("BODY", body)
                                res.on('data', (d) => {
                                    body += d;
                                });
                                res.on('end', () => {
                                    console.log("END", body)
                                    pdfdoc.image(body, x, y);
                                    resolve(body);
                                });
                            });
                            req.on('error', err => {
                                console.error('error!');
                                reject(err);
                            });

                        });

                    }
```